# A Question Regarding TikZ ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-node

In the Tik Z & PGF Manual for Version 2.10-CVS, page 130/880 there is an example to create a pair of a circle and an ellipse as below:

[image]

Below is the code I used:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\path (0,0) node(a) [ellipse,rotate=10,draw] {An ellipse}
(3,-1) node(b) [circle,draw] {A circle};
\draw[thick] (node cs:name=a) -- (node cs:name=b);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

However I got an error as below:
! Package pgfkeys Error: I do not know the key '/tikz/ellipse' and I am going t
o ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it.
Do you know how to fix this? Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: why don't you use the latest version 3.1.5b ? https://ctan.org/pkg/pgf?lang=en

Comment: Yes you are right. I got the latest manual in your link. Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When using `ellipse` as a node shape, you need to load the `shapes.geometric` tikz library.
You can do that by adding `\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric}` in your preamble (usually immediately) after `\usepackage{tikz}`.
Note that you don't need `shapes.geometric` to draw an ellipse, only to use it as a node shape like in your example.
You could also use `\usetikzlibrary{shapes}` to include all `shapes` sublibraries (including `shapes.geometric`) but it's deprecated, see the PGF manual quoted by Zarko in his [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/553293/219497):

> Note that the library shapes is provided for compatibility only. Please include sublibraries like shapes.geometric or shapes.misc directly.

Comment: @Étienne, welcome to TeX.SE! excellent answer by the way! +1

Answer (score 10):

As supplement to the [Étienne answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553289/a-question-regarding-tikz-ellipse/553290#553290):

- Tik Z & PGF Manual for Version 2.10-CVS is obsolete for years, I strongly recommend to use the recent version of the package as well as its manual.
- Actual version of TikZ manual is 3.1.5b (January 8, 2020), where your example is on page 141.
- Shapes Library is described in chapter *72 Shape Library* starting at page 785, where in section *72 Shape Library* is stated:

> In addition to the standard shapes rectangle, circle and coordinate, there exist a number of additional shapes defined in different shape libraries. Most of these shapes have been contributed by Mark Wibrow. In the present section, these shapes are described. Note that the library shapes is provided for compatibility only. Please include sublibraries like shapes.geometric or shapes.misc directly.

- Geometric shapes are described in section *72.3 Geometric Shapes* on page 786.
- For ellipse shape see pages 787 -- 788.

Comment: Yes thank you so much. I downloaded the newest TikZ manual.

Comment: @Aria, I suggest you to upgrade the TikZ package too!